# How to access the values from while returning the Object

Tags: apex, wrapper-class

```
public class TestWrapperClass {

    public class InnerWrapper{
        private String name;
        private String location;

        public String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getLocation() {
            return this.location;
        }

        public void getLocation(String age) {
            this.location = age;
        }

    }

    public static InnerWrapper getDetailsObj(){
        InnerWrapper var = new InnerWrapper();
        var.getLocation('NY') ;
        var.setName('XYZ');
        return var;
    }

}
```

This is how I am trying to get the values

```
Object obj  = TestWrapperClass.getDetailsObj();
List<Object> listObject = new List<Object>();
listObject.add(obj);

System.debug( listObject );
```

> (InnerWrapper:[location=NY, name=XYZ])

Question: How can I access the values of *location* and *name*.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @DavidReed -  I tried this listObject.get(0).get('name') and getting incorrect signature: void get(String) error. Looking for some guidance how to handle  this.

Comment: @DavidReed thanks for quick response :)

Answer (score 2):

The `Object` base class doesn't have the `get()` method, which is available only on SObjects. Apex doesn't have generalized dynamic property access as you would find in languages like JavaScript or Python.

You'll need to either cast the return value of `listObject.get()` to obtain a concretely-typed instance of `TestWrapperClass`, or switch all of your references to `Object` to that actual class name (which is almost certainly what you should be doing).

Then, call the methods defined on that class on the instance you receive:

```
TestWrapperClass.InnerWrapper obj  = TestWrapperClass.getDetailsObj();
List<TestWrapperClass.InnerWrapper> listObject = new List<TestWrapperClass.InnerWrapper>();
listObject.add(obj);

System.debug( listObject.get(0).getName() );
```